# Can we disable user interactions with other applications in mac while our app is running?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am working on a mac based application and need guidance on one of the features, what I am trying to do here is

When my app launches I don't want the user to interact with any other application unless the user hits the close button of the app. No keyboard shortcuts should be enabled for mac like cmd+spacebar etc.

My question is if this is doable? Is there official documentation from apple which says it won't allow doing this due to some technical reason?

Comment: Search for "kiosk" mode. There are several questions regarding this on Stack Overflow, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32809974/233944

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/KioskMode/Introduction/Introduction.html and https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2062/_index.html then review the API documentation (and release notes) to see what's changed since those docs were last updated.

Comment: @TheNextman can you please add your answer as a comment so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

macOS has supported "kiosk mode" since 10.6; it allows your application to:

- Hide / deactivate the dock, menu bar and Apple menu
- Disable switching and hiding of your application
- Prevent restarting or shutting down the computer

Broadly,`NSApplication` exposes a bitmask property, `NSApplicationPresentationOptions`, that lets you select the combination of settings you want to use.

The best resource to read further is the archived documentation that @KenThomases located [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/KioskMode/Introduction/Introduction.html) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2062/_index.html).